# How to give hover effect in bar chart flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

This is how I represent my bar chart in a Scaffold body, I want to give label for each bar I tried using `labelAccessorFn:` but its not working. Atleast a help me how to do hover effect when user touch a bar how to show the that particular bar value if there is no way atleast how to label each and every bar.please help me out.

FYI: `KilometeresPerDay` is a class where I store data.

```
var series = [
      new charts.Series(
        domainFn: (KilometeresPerDay clickData, _) => clickData.day,
        measureFn: (KilometeresPerDay clickData, _) => clickData.kms,
        colorFn: (KilometeresPerDay clickData, _) => clickData.color,
        id: 'Clicks',
        data: data,
      ),
    ];

    var chart = new charts.BarChart(
      series,
      animate: true,
    );

    var chartWidget = new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 250.0,
        child: chart,
      ),
    );
```